# Zod recursive type with discriminated union

Tags: typescript, zod

How to transform this recursive discriminated union to zod?

```
interface TextInput {
  type: 'text-input'
}

interface Group {
  type: 'group';
  components: AppComponent[]
}

type AppComponent = TextInput | Group

const component: AppComponent = {
  type: 'group',
  components: [{
    type: 'text-input'
  }],
}
```

what would the zod version look like?

My attempt:

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const TextInputSchema = z.object({
    type: z.literal('text-input'),
});

const GroupSchema = z.object({
    type: z.literal('group'),
    components: z.array(ComponentSchema),
});

const ComponentSchema = z.discriminatedUnion('type', [TextInputSchema, GroupSchema]);
```

but that doesn't work due to the error that `[...] type is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer`.

Comment: You need `z.lazy` or whatever

Comment: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#recursive-types

Answer (score 2):

the key here is to use z.lazy which let's us use zod types that haven't yet been completely defined.

```js
import {z} from "zod"

interface TextInput {
  type: 'text-input'
}

interface Group {
  type: 'group';
  components: AppComponent[]
}

type AppComponent = TextInput | Group

const TextInput = z.object({
  type: z.literal("text-input")
})

const Group: z.ZodType<Group> = z.lazy(() => z.object({
  type: z.literal("group"),
  components: AppComponent.array()
}))

const AppComponent = TextInput.or(Group)

const component = AppComponent.parse({
  type: 'group',
  components: [
    { type: 'text-input' }, 
    { 
      type: "group",
      components: [
        { type: 'text-input' }
      ]
    }
  ],
})

console.log(component)
```

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answer uses a [union type](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod?tab=readme-ov-file#unions) rather than a [discriminated union](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod?tab=readme-ov-file#discriminated-unions) as requested in the question. It is possible to use recursive discriminated union types in Zod, but the example they give in [Zod documentation](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod?tab=readme-ov-file#recursive-types) must be slightly modified.

Here is an example:

```js
const TextInputSchema = z.object({
  type: z.literal('text-input'),
});

const BaseGroupSchema = z.object({
  type: z.literal("group"),
});

type Group = z.infer<typeof BaseGroupSchema> & {
  components: Component[];
}

const GroupSchema: z.ZodDiscriminatedUnionOption<"type"> = BaseGroupSchema.extend({
  components: z.lazy(() => z.array(ComponentSchema))
})

const ComponentSchema = z.discriminatedUnion('type', [
  TextInputSchema,
  GroupSchema
]);

type Component = z.infer<typeof ComponentSchema>;
```

Notice that **type of `GroupSchema` is `z.ZodDiscriminatedUnionOption<"type">`** rather than `z.ZodType<Group>` as one may think from the documentation examples.

---

The code above can be tested with this example:

```js
const testInput = {
  type: 'group', components: [
    { type: 'text-input' },
    { type: 'group', components: [
        { type: 'text-input' }
     ]}
]}

console.log(ComponentSchema.parse(testInput)) ;
// {
//      type: 'group',
//      components: [ { type: 'text-input' }, { type: 'group', components: [Array] } ]
// }
```